# Kubernetes pod failing because of incorrect container command

Tags: kubernetes, makefile, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-operator

I am creating a egress-operator. I have a pod `egress-operator-controller-manager` created from [makefile](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator/blob/master/Makefile) by command `make deploy IMG=my_azure_repo/egress-operator:v0.1`. The pod is failing , its showing error in pod description as:

```
  State:          Waiting
  Reason:       RunContainerError
  Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       StartError
  Message:      failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/manager": stat /manager: no such file or directory: unknown
  Failed     44s (x3 over 59s)  kubelet  Error: failed to create containerd task: 
  OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: 
  exec: "/manager": stat /manager: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I suspect that in `manager.yaml`, under `command:` [/manager](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator/blob/2bb1a423cc8d6c556d5a746dabf401fa59754573/config/manager/manager.yaml#L51) is executed.
Can someone let me know what is going wrong in this `manager.yaml` and whether [`/manager`](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator/blob/2bb1a423cc8d6c556d5a746dabf401fa59754573/config/manager/manager.yaml#L51) is valid under `command:` in deployment.yaml

**Debugging UPDATE** 
Instead of running Dockerfile, now I just build and run `image_azure_repo/egress-operator:v0.1` locally (on same ubuntu 18 VM), When I try to login with: `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`, I am getting error :

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: 
starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: 
no such file or directory: unknown
```

This is similar error what I see in pod description. Instead of `/bin/bash` , I also tried `docker exec` with `/bin/sh` and only `sh` ; Its giving same error

Comment: Sounds like you're not using the right image -- looking at their Dockerfile, that /manager thing should be there. Either it's not the right version, or not the controler. Is it normal your tag mentions some `v0.1`, while the default value in that Makefile would use something like `manager-$gitref`?

Comment: @SYN-: I followed https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#set-up-the-controller-manager-and-its-customresourcedefinition-in-the-cluster to make deploy IMG=my_azure_repo/egress-operator:v0.1 .

Comment: If you inspect your local copy of that image, are you sure there's a `/manager` in there?

Comment: I tried running Dockerfile separately on local, build happened successfully but "docker run -d imageName" is not keeping container up. the container is exiting as docker run in executed. So I cant login to container and confirm whether /manager is there or not

Comment: @SYN-: Instead of Dockerfile, now I just build and run image y_azure_repo/egress-operator:v0.1 locally, When I try to login with: "docker exec -it modest_jones /bin/bash", I am getting error : OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown . this is similar error what I see in pod description. I have updated my Que. with this info

Comment: Sure, the base image that /manager is copied to doesn't have a shell. You could  switch the last FROM for something like `alpine:latest`, in case you want to check. Though if you're at the stage of running `docker exec`, then it means the container runs, doesn't it? it managed to find its entrypoint after all?

Comment: When created container from Dockerfile image, docker container exits. When created container from image_azure_repo/egress-operator:v0.1 image, docker container is up, but still /bin/bash error comes. so as you suggested I am checking with  alpine:latest image in dockerfile.

Comment: @SYN-: You suspect correct, the problem is with line 22, FROM gcr.io/distroless/static:nonroot . When I replaced it with From alpine:latest. Its working. I dont know why they are using https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless image . but now  USER nonroot:nonroot line giving error as : 
docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user nonroot: no matching entries in passwd file.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: alpine probably has some `nobody:nobody` instead. Stick with distroless: your image starts: entrypoint was found, how about in kubernetes?

Comment: In alpine, last ENTRYPOINT[/manager] is giving error:
ERROR   controller-runtime.client.config     unable to get kubeconfig    {"error": "could not locate a kubeconfig"}
github.com/go-logr/zapr.(*zapLogger).Error
  /go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-logr/zapr@v0.1.0/zapr.go:128
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client/config.GetConfigOrDie
  /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.4.0/pkg/client/config/config.go:146
main.main
  /workspace/main.go:63
runtime.main
I commented last line, able to login to container and manually fired /manager command, giving same error

Comment: In distroless, with ENTRYPOINT, getting same error as alpine. but if I am commenting last line then docker run -it testimage giving error as-: docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'.

The same docker run command working for alpine and distroless(with ENTRYPOINT line) but not working with distroless(without ENTRYPOINT line)

Comment: @SYN-: To avoid mess I think I will create another que dedicated only to run dockerfie with distroless image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a mismatch for libc.

Golang uses glibc by default while alpine uses musl.

You could try those to fix it:

1. Use a base image using glibc
2. Install glibc in your alpine image

Comment: Can I use same distroless image with glibc instead of alpine? and install glibc in dockerfile ?

Comment: Of cause you can. But I am not sure which libc the distroless have, maybe it’s glibc by default and you don’t have to install it

Comment: @PapEr-: I am using distroless in que where /manager not found issue coming. As per distroless doc https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/base/README.md#documentation-for-gcriodistrolessbase-and-gcriodistrolessstatic , they are using glibc. Quote from link: "Most other applications (and Go apps that require libc/cgo) should start with gcr.io/distroless/base, which contains all of the packages in gcr.io/distroless/static, and
- glibc"

Comment: @solveit So can you make sure which distroless image you are using? From your repo I found in question, it’s is distroless/static which is bared without libc

Comment: @PapEr-: I replaced distroless/static with distroless/base as per https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/base/README.md#image-contents It worked now. Thanks a lot. you are genius :-)

Answer (score 2):

- In Dockerfile , the Entrypoint you have mentioned is `ENTRYPOINT ["/manager"]` but shouldnt it be `ENTRYPOINT ["./manager"]`
- regarding "starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: " , it seems base image does not have `/bin/bash` it might have just `/bin/sh`